# Applying lein-ring's :init to deployed JAR?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure

I have a Compojure app that has the following :ring entry in project.clj:

:ring {:handler       myapp.handler/app
       :init          myapp.export/scheduler-init}

When I deploy as a WAR (under Wildfly), the "app" function specified by :handler is being used, but the scheduler-init specified by :init is not.

Is "lein ring uberwar" supposed to to roll these up automatically, and if not, how do I specify an :init for my uberwar?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be automatically included. In my case, it isn't. I will amend later if there's a useful generality to be learned.

UPDATE: If you have a web.xml, apparently, lein-ring won't alter or modify it.